# how do i prevent values in JS object from being removed everytime i call the function that adds values to this object?

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I have made the object global and
I have parsed the values to a string before adding to the object

```
var myObj = {"my":"obj"};

{ key: '_performAddEdge',
  value: function _performAddEdge(sourceNodeId, targetNodeId) {
      var _this5 = this;
      var sourceJobName = String(this.body.nodes[sourceNodeId].options.label.trim());
      var targetJobName =  String(this.body.nodes[targetNodeId].options.lab.trim());
      myObj [sourceJobName] = targetJobName;
      console.log(myObj );}
```

**Results 1st time i call the function**

```
{"my": "obj", "Job_1": "Job_1_value"}
```

**Results 2nd time i call the function**

```
{"my": "obj", "Job_2": "Job_2_value"}
```

**Expected Results for 2nd call**

```
{"my": "obj", "Job_1":"Job_1_value","Job_2":"Job_2_value"}
```

Comment: ↵ means line break and if you want to remove it then you have to use regex over the values

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a carriage return possibly from the label.

You could try trimming your value

```js
let a = `asdf


`;

console.log(a)

console.log(a.trim())
```

We don't see a the enter arrow. But in this output do see the excess white space? Try updating your code to trim first. If it is a carriage return this should remove it.

`var sourceJobName = String(this.body.nodes[sourceNodeId].options.label.trim());`

Comment: Thanks Lex, the carriage return has been removed but the issue of my values being removed everytime this function is called still exists